# Child.prototype = Parent.prototype vs Child.prototype = new Parent()

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

After the definition of some constructor function, e.g. `Child`, I've seen both of the following forms:

```
Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;
```

*or*

```
Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

Are both correct?  And if so, is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: Preferred way nowadays: `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)`

Comment: In the first version, both constructors share the same prototype. This means the Child cannot have its own prototype methods. And if you create a GrandChild prototype using the same method, it would actually inherit from the Parent.

Comment: Combined with what elclanrs said, you also will sometimes see `Parent.call(this);` at the beginning of `Child`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although @elclanrs' comment is correct, and these days you might prefer Object.create, and choose to shim it for older environments, there is a clear-cut right answer to your question.

```
Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

is far superior to

```
Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;
```

For the simple reason that in the latter, any properties you then add to the child prototype are also included in the parent.  When

```
Dog.prototype = Animal.prototype;
dog.prototype.bark = function() {console.log("woof, woof");}
Cat.prototype = Animal.prototype;
var frisky = new Cat();
frisky.bark(); //=> woof, woof!
```

You've got cats and dogs living together... mass hysteria.